# Compressing TIFF figure with constant resolution

Tags: export, compression, tiff-format

I need to compress the TIFF figure "p5"(originally around 25 mb) in to less than 1 mb or as small as possible with constant resolution of 600 dpi.

```
ClearAll[a1, plot1, b1, plot2, f]
a1 = {{0.82, -109}, {0.98, -75}, {1.12, -57}, {1.17, -52}, {1.30,-43}, 
{1.37, -38}, {1.45, -34}, {1.54, -30}, {1.64, -26}, {1.76,-22.9}, {1.95, 
-18.6}, {2.06, -16.6}, {2.24, -13.8}, {2.47, -11.2},{2.74, -8.9}, {3.09, 
-6.8}, {3.53, -5}, {3.80, -4.17}, {4.12, -3.4},{4.59, -2.55}, {4.94, -2.06}, 
{5.26, -1.70}, {5.62, -1.37}, {5.83,-1.20}, {6.18, -0.96}, {6.51, -0.77}, 
{6.87, -0.58}};
plot1 = ListLinePlot[a1, PlotStyle -> Blue,PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {15,-115}}, 
FrameLabel -> {{"ka",None}, {"Photon energy (eV)", "Ag"}}, Frame -> {{True, 
False}, {True, True}},ImagePadding -> 70, ImageSize -> Large, FrameStyle -> 
{{Blue, Black}, {Black, Black}},LabelStyle -> {14, GrayLevel[0]},FrameTicks 
-> {{Transpose[{#, Map[PaddedForm[#, {3, 1}] &, #]}]&[Range[-120, 10, 20]], 
Automatic}, {Transpose[{#, Map[PaddedForm[#, {2, 1}] &, #]}] &[Range[0, 7, 
1.0]], Automatic}}]
b1 = {{0.82, 12.33}, {0.98, 7.06}, {1.12, 4.81}, {1.17, 4.19}, {1.30, 3.10}, 
{1.37, 2.66}, {1.45, 2.22}, {1.54, 1.87}, {1.64, 1.53}, {1.76, 1.24}, {1.95, 
0.92}, {2.06, 0.78}, {2.24, 0.60}, {2.47, 0.45}, {2.74, 0.33}, {3.09, 0.23}, 
{3.53, 0.15}, {3.80, 0.12}, {4.12, 0.098}, {4.59, 0.071}, {4.94, 0.056}, 
{5.26, 0.047}, {5.62, 0.038}, {5.83, 0.034}, {6.18, 0.029}, {6.51, 0.024}, 
{6.87, 0.021}};
plot2 = ListLinePlot[b1, PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {-2.0, 14}}, PlotStyle -> 
Red, ImagePadding -> 70, ImageSize -> Large, FrameLabel -> {{None, "kb"}, 
{"Photon energy (eV)", None}}, Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, False}}, 
FrameStyle -> {{Black, Red}, {Black, Black}}, LabelStyle -> {14, 
GrayLevel[0]}, FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Transpose[{#, Map[PaddedForm[#, 
{3, 1}] &, #]}] &[Range[-2, 14, 2.0]]}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]
f = Overlay[{plot1, plot2}]  
Export["p5.tiff", Import[Export["p5.pdf", f, ImageSize -> 10,ImageResolution 
-> 600]],ImageResolution -> 600]
```

Comment: Why are you exporting as PDF, then reimporting, then exporting as TIFF?

Comment: @MarcoB, if i don't export as pdf and only export as a tiff file with image resolution 600 dpi. Then the export tiff file will loss all the tricks along the axis. I need to have a tiff files with 600 dpi

Comment: @MarcoB, the codes "ZIP" when used, the graph losses all the frame ticks. Could you help me for retaining the frameticks please.

Comment: Please see the edit to my answer to included export / and re-import.

Comment: @MarcoB, Thank you so much. It works perfectly. The top x-axis has more frame ticks than the bottom x-axis. Would you suggest me how to get the top x-axis frameticks (without numbers labels) similar to the bottom x-axis ticks . Thank you once again

Answer (score 3):

Using your code to generate the `f` image, then specify an image encoding when you export as TIFF, e.g. ZIP:

```
Export["p5ZIP.tiff", f, ImageResolution -> 600, "ImageEncoding" -> "ZIP"]
```

The unencoded file is roughly 40 MB on my computer, whereas the ZIP-encoded one is 147 kB (!), at the same resolution (i.e. both images are 4800 x 3412 pixels).

The [docs for the TIFF format](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/TIFF.html) indicate that you can use:

```
None        no compression                         (40  MB  for f)
"JPEG"      lossy JPEG compression                 (FAILED  for f)
"LZW"       lossless LZW compression               (160 kB  for f)
"PackBits"  PackBits run-length encoding method    (1.5 MB  for f)
"ZIP"       lossless ZIP image data compression    (143 kB  for f)
```

`PackBits` is not the most efficient compression method, but it has the advantage that *any* TIFF reader is required to handle that format, according to the standard (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF).

---

To fix the problem that the axis ticks go missing when exporting to TIFF directly, which must be a bug, you already had found the workaround to go through the PDF format. I'd only suggest to do that using `ExportString` and `ImportString`, so you avoid generating the useless auxiliary files:

```
Export[
  "p5.tif",
  ImportString[ExportString[f, "PDF"], "PDF"],
  ImageResolution -> 600, "ImageEncoding" -> "ZIP"
]
```

The generated TIFF file (3458x2475 pixels) is small in file size (116 kB), has resolution of 600 dpi as reported by e.g. Windows Explorer, and the ticks are retained.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly. The top x-axis has more frame ticks than the bottom x-axis. Would you suggest me how to get the top x-axis frameticks (without numbers) similar to the bottom x-axis ticks. Thank you once again MarcoB